# Change z-index of div with fade effect on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, z-order, fading

I have 4 images stacked on top of each other, see below:
[image: http://img148.imageshack.us/img148/9096/48404002.jpg]

I'm trying to achieve two things:

1. When the mouse is over an image that is in the background, that
   image should come to the foreground with a fading effect. There is
   also different text below each image, that text should come to the
   foreground. (no fading needed there)

   The result should be like this:
   [image: http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/5663/58906919.jpg]
2. Every 10-15 seconds (without user input), the next image on the right should fade in
   automatically.

Technically, I thought about putting each image and text into a separate div, and playing with the z-order. The fading effect could maybe be achieved using jquery, but I've not used that before, unfortunately.

Any example code, specific help or pointers is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: All images are visible. What does mean "come to foreground with a fading effect"?

Comment: Sorry, cannot transition z-index. You can fade the opacity of a layer, but as far as fading them vertically *through* eachother... no can do with javascript/css.

Comment: Chris, that is bad news. Could you propose any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's impossible to control the *fade* of an element through his **z-index**
we can always trick what our eyes see.

### [DEMO GALLERY](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/aS7V9/)

[image]

To achieve that we can do:

- **Insert into our gallery a DIV element** that will grab the `src` attribute of the *current image* and set it as his background image
- hide the current image, position the DIV on this image .position()
- **fade our DIV in/out**
- reset image visibility

Let me know if you have some issues, I can comment my code to make clearer the steps I used.

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this plugin. Just explore it, this has got 100s of different effects which you might like to use in your case.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/browser.html

Comment: My problem with plugins is that you usually spend more time exploring and rewriting the code to your needs than creating your own solution...